# What is the Process Builder equivalent of: "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria"

Tags: process-builder

I am have a workflow rule which updates the field on quote and creates task 3 Days Before Quote Expiration Date.I have to move this rule to Process Builder and I can only see two evaluation criteria in process builder:

[image]

The workflow rule has third evaluation criteria "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria".What is equivalent of this criteria in Process builder?What should I select for this criteria in Process Builder?

Is "Recursion - Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction" same as above criteria?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click [4] `Add Criteria`

[image]

---

2. Check the `Advanced` part at the end.

> Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are
>   made to the record?

It is similar to "*Recursion - Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction*" in workflow rule.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" is similar to "Recursion - Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction"?

Comment: You can better test it by creating a flow in org, I have been using this feature since its introduction and it's working.

Comment: I have as well, and I don't see why those 2 settings would be similar. "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" is similar to "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria".